# Showing JFrame in realtime as it changes

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouseevent

So what I would like to accomplish is create two JFrames. One will cover the whole screen and when a user clicks on that screen a new JFrame shows up when the user clicks and drags the mouse. Where the user first clicks is the top left corner of the new JFrame and where the user releases the mouse is the bottom right corner of the JFrame. I have no problem making the two JFrames and making the second JFrame show up when the mouse is clicked and released. What the problem is I want the new JFrame to show in realtime when the user is moving the mouse around so before the mouse is released. I tried

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

            FrontWindow f = new FrontWindow();

            while (true) {          
                f.setBounds(Shared.xPressed, Shared.yPressed, (Utils.getXPosition() - Shared.xPressed) , (Utils.getYPosition() - Shared.yPressed));
                f.setVisible(true);
            }

        }
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: Do you want the JFrame itself to appear or is an outline of it sufficient?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of blocked Event Dispatching Thread.  Your code is not only going to prevent your application from processing any new events, but it is also going to prevent it from performing any updates/repaints

Comment: @MonadNewb An outline of the JFrame is sufficient as long as the shape is changing as the mouse moves.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can you explain what is wrong with my code?

Comment: What is all this supposed to achieve for the end user?  Describe it to me as if I were a potential user and it was an application feature I 'must have'.

Comment: @user2512789 Your code takes control of the Event Dispatching Thread (EDT) which means that your program will not recieve any other events until your `mouseDragged()` method completes.

Comment: The mouseDragged() method will never comlete because of the while loop.

Comment: If the outline is enough, just use @camickr solution drawing a rectangle, it's more elegant. And also think about what Andrew said. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for a while loop. Multiple mouseDragged() events will be generated.

You should be creating the new frame on a mousePressed() event. Then when each mouseDragged() event is generated you change the size of the frame.

Of course this will not look great since the dragging will not be in sync with the size of the frame. A better approach is to just draw a rectangle as you move the mouse. Then on mouseReleased you create and display the frame at the size of the drawn rectangle.

See [Custom Paint Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for the basics of drawing a Rectangle with the mouse. In your case you might want to use a Glass Pane to handle the mouse events and drawing of the rectangle.

Comment: I provided you with a working example. Both of the examples draw the Rectangle dynamically. On mouseReleased then save the Rectangles. In your case instead of saving the Rectangle you would create your frame using the current bounds of the Rectangle.Take a look at the code, try it and then ask questions.

Answer (score 2):

`while (true)` in your `mouseDragged()` event handler blocks Swing's Event Dispatcher Thread (EDT). This means that your program will not recieve any additional events. So when the user first starts to drag the mouse, you start this infinite loop. But the OS is not able to notify you that the mouse continues to move as the user drags it because you have blocked its ability to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()` in a separate thread, using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Point mp = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        f.setBounds(Shared.xPress, Shared.yPress, mp.x - Shared.xPress, mp.y - Shared.yPressed);
    }
}
```

N.B. `invokeLater()` does not *start* a separate thread. You should *create* a new thread and call `invokeLater()` in its `run()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Swing is a single threaded framework.  That is, it uses a single thread to dispatch all it's events to all it's interested parties.

If anything blocks this thread (such as a infinate `while-loop`), then the thread is unable to process any new events coming into the application, including repaint requests.  This will make your application look like it's hung (which in your case, it actually has).

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

The following example allows a use to click/drag across the surface of the window and it will render a rectangle representing the drag process.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class DrawRectangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DrawRectangle();
    }

    public DrawRectangle() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Rectangle dragRect;

        public TestPane() {

            MouseHandler handler = new MouseHandler();
            addMouseListener(handler);
            addMouseMotionListener(handler);

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            if (dragRect != null) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                g2d.draw(dragRect);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        public class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {

            private Point clicked;

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                clicked = e.getPoint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

                Point p = e.getPoint();

                int x = Math.min(p.x, clicked.x);
                int y = Math.min(p.y, clicked.y);

                int width = Math.max(p.x, clicked.x) - x;
                int height = Math.max(p.y, clicked.y) - y;

                dragRect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
                repaint();

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, and thank you to the other user for the idea of drawing a square instead.

Going to look at the code and add it with my program.